# module 'Orange' has no attribute 'feature'

Tags: python, python-3.5, orange

I can import Orange but when I try to run the following:

```
import Orange as o
import numpy as np

auc_array = np.asarray(auction[nf])
auc = o.data.Table(auc_array)
imputer = o.feature.imputation.ModelConstructor()
imputer.learner_continuous = imputer.learner_discrete = Orange.classification.tree.TreeLearner(min_subset=20)
imputer = imputer(auc)
print(auc)
```

I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-1b6636bf45a4> in <module>()
      4 auc_array = np.asarray(auction[nf])
      5 auc = o.data.Table(auc_array)
----> 6 imputer = o.feature.imputation.ModelConstructor()
      7 imputer.learner_continuous = imputer.learner_discrete = Orange.classification.tree.TreeLearner(min_subset=20)
      8 imputer = imputer(auc)

AttributeError: module 'Orange' has no attribute 'feature'
```

I also tried importing Orange.feature and the code still didn't work:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-78641fe044ef> in <module>()
      1 import Orange as o
----> 2 import Orange.feature
      3 import numpy as np
      4 
      5 auc_array = np.asarray(auction[nf])

ImportError: No module named 'Orange.feature'
```

Comment: Why do you believe that it should exist?

Comment: It seems that you read Orange 2.7 documentation. In Orange 3, you may have to check Impute in Orange.preprocess module. Since I can find some [documentation](https://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/data-mining-library/reference/preprocess.html), which uses `from Orange.preprocess import Impute`